# CSRF token not validated from times to times

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, csrf

I use Codeigniter/PHP. I use CSRF tokens (not the CI native version as I have my own form implementation) and from time to time the token is not validated.

The CSRF token is created once per session:

```
function create_csrf_token() //If needed, creates a session variable; returns a hash to use for CSRF protection
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    if($CI->session->userdata('csrfToken')) //the token already exists: use its hash
    {
        $csrfHash = $CI->session->userdata('csrfToken');
    }
    else //no token yet: create session variable + set its hash
    {
        $csrfHash = base64_encode(hash('sha256', uniqid(serialize($_SERVER), true), true));
        $CI->session->set_userdata(array('csrfToken' => $csrfHash));            
    }
    return $csrfHash;
}
```

It is passed to the form without issues in the csrfToken hidden input field, with `htmlspecialchars` applied to it (using `urlencode` makes no difference):

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$this->name.'" value="'.htmlspecialchars($this->value).'">';
```

This field has a validation rule `verify_csrf`:

```
public function verify_csrf($token)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    if($CI->session->userdata('csrfToken') && $CI->session->userdata('csrfToken') == $token) return true;
    else
    {
        $this->set_message('verify_csrf', 'Invalid token');
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is where things get weird. Sometimes `$token` is not correct and looks like corrupted data. Here are a couple of examples:

**Error**:

Value in `$CI->session->userdata('csrfToken')`: `6cT3O0KTOk7cVlear71lU7KKFlGONt4rS2HjNoSVFRM=` (correct)

Value in `$token`: `6cT O0KTOk7cVlear71lU7KKFlG` (4th character changed and missing end of string)

**No error**:

Value in `$CI->session->userdata('csrfToken')`: `AiAgGqqxTxuCxN7h5HHRtcJjmHJVMRksBYbq6Dx4Kv4=`

Value in `$token`: `AiAgGqqxTxuCxN7h5HHRtcJjmHJVMRksBYbq6Dx4Kv4=`

Any idea? I have checked and rechecked, the CRSF token is correctly set everywhere except in $token in my validation callback. And it only happens for certain tokens...

EDIT: so it seems that the base64 encoding was causing the issue (why, I don't know). I have replaced

```
$csrfHash = base64_encode(hash('sha256', uniqid(serialize($_SERVER), true), true));
```

by

```
$csrfHash = random_string('sha1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a wild guess, but could it be the combination of the Base64 encoding and submitting the form via HTTP POST, like described here:

[POST Base64 encoded data in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206666/post-base64-encoded-data-in-php)

The solution could then be to urlencode() the token before posting?

**EDIT:** The solution turns out to be dropping the base64 encoding of the token in favor of a plain sha256-hash as a token. See comments below.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately this makes no difference (I forgot to mention that I was already using htmlspecialchars when generating the html for the csrfToken field - replacing it by urlencode still shows the same issue)

Comment: Could it be something related to the Content-Type or enctype-attribute of the form (i.e. "multipart/form-data")?

Comment: Typical form: <form action="" method="post"> with <meta charset='utf-8'> in html head.

Comment: I am wondering if there's a particular reason to base64 encode the token, rather than just passing the sha256 hash as a token? (Just to verify that the problem is not related to the base64 encoded data)

Comment: Yes I thought the same and replaced the whole thing by $csrfHash = random_string('sha1'); (using the native CI string helper) which seems to work now! If you edit your initial solution to mention that as solution I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the config for the CSRF.

You can enable csrf protection by opening your application/config/config.php file and setting this:

`$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`

// This will automatically generate the hidden field for    `form_open(params)`    function, so you no need to do it every time. This feature is included the frame work.

To avoid CSRF to specific URIs
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/182631/

Comment: As explained the site uses a much more sophisticated form system, which typically does not use form_open. Changing that requires basically refactoring everything.